# work with sql server views in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to load data to gridview from view in sql server. But how to do it? 
For example for database tables I've got different(generated by vs) table adapters like TClientTableAdapter,TShopsTableAdapter and etc. But I don't see any for view(view - TVProvider)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no difference between table & view, you can just consider it as table & do work with that. just consider view is a table & do programme, it can load data just as table

Comment: I work with tables using generated by visual studio tables adapters. But I don't see table adapter for my view.